# Latexmk: Disallowing switch of output file as incompatible with file requests

Tags: latexmk

I compile a source code with that command:

```
$ latexmk -pdf main.tex
```

Later, I want to clean the folder (indeed, it is part of the `make clean` rule, but it does not matter).

```
$ latexmk -C
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 March 2019, version: 4.63b.
Latexmk: Disallowing switch of output file as incompatible
    with file requests.
```

Why is this warning message (2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> line) generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching in the code of `latexmk` where this warning message is generated shown this comment:

```
if ( $dvi_mode || $postscript_mode
     || ( $printout_mode && ($print_type eq 'ps') || ($print_type eq 'dvi') )
     || ( ($preview_mode || $preview_continuous_mode)  &&  ( ($view eq 'ps') || ($view eq 'dvi') ) )
   ) {
    # Automatic switching (e.g., pdf<->dvi o/p) requires pdf files to be
    # the only destinations.  So if ps or dvi files needed, we cannot
    # allow switching.  (There will then be an error condition if a TeX
    # engine fails to produce the correct type of output file.)
    warn "$My_name: Disallowing switch of output file as incompatible\n",
         "    with file requests.\n";
    $can_switch = 0;
}
```

So, instead of just saying to `latexmk` to clean, specify that you want it to clean all files generated while compiling to PDF:

```
$ latexmk -pdf -C
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 March 2019, version: 4.63b.
```

(Add `-quiet` to the command to get rid of the last line, which is only an information and not a warning.)

Comment: @daleif Yep.  Here, `pdf` is used to specify that you had compiled with `-pdf` previously, so you want to drop these files.  Imagine you had compiled with `-ps` (so .ps files are produce) and you fire a `-pdf -C` cleanup…  Should `latexmk` clean the .ps files?  That's the aim of the warning.

Comment: My bad, I wasn't paying attention. Note that I'd always use `latexmk -C *.tex`